# Show that for big enough $n$ the diameter in almost any graph on $n$ vertices is 2

Tags: probability

> Show that for big enough $n$, the diameter in almost any graph on $n$
>   vertices is $2$.
>
> Specifically, show that the number of graphs with diameter at most $2$
>   is at least: $2^{n \choose 2}\cdot(1- {n \choose
> > 2}(\frac{3}{4})^{n-2})$.

I am stuck on that question. I tried using random graph with probability half on each edge but it didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every graph in $G(n, p)$ has diameter $2$.

If a graph is of diameter bigger than $2$, then it must have at least two vertices like $u$ and $v$ with disjoint neighbors. Then all of the other vertices of the graph must be adjacent to at most one of $u$ and $v$. So number of the graphs having no paths of size less than $3$ between $u$ and $v$ for a fixed pair of vertices $(u,v)=3^{n-2}2^{\binom{n-2}{2}}$. By considering
all of pairs of vertices like $u$ and $v$, the number of the graphs with diameter at least $3$ is at most $\dbinom{3}{2}3^{n-2}2^{\binom{n-2}{2}}$

Now since we have $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \dfrac{\dbinom{3}{2}3^{n-2}2^{\binom{n-2}{2}}}{2^{\binom{n}{2}}} } $, we are done.